# sql running total modification

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with columns: *ID*, *Type* (with 'IN' and 'Out' strings), and *Value* (holding money data)

I need to get the balance of each row by summing and minus of *Value*, following the logic:

- if Type = 'In' then sum Value
- if Type = 'Out' then minus Value

I have tried something but I can't determine wherever there is in or out:

```
ID  Type      Value  and in balance like this Balance
21  In        55                              55
22  IN        78                              133
23  Out       15                              118
24  Out       56                              62
25  In        72                              134
26  Out       5                               129
```

I have code like this:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        Value ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(y.Value)
          FROM      dbo.Reestr y
          WHERE     y.ID <= x.ID

        ) AS RunningTotal
FROM    dbo.Reestr x
ORDER BY 1 ,2 ,3;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the cumulative sum function.  This is available in SQL Server 2012+:

```
select r.id, r.value,
       sum(case when r.type = 'in' then value
                when r.type = 'out' then - value
           end) over (order by r.id) as balance
from dbo.Reestr r
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

You can do the same thing with a correlated subquery, by including the `case` expression in the subquery.

Comment: @Ravi . . . The code in the question doesn't have a `group by`.  Nor does the data suggest that one is needed.  If you have a question about cumulative sums with aggregation, then ask a question.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff....You are using aggregate function you have to use group by clause because Id is not in aggregate function. If question doesnt have it thats why he is not getting desired result,

Comment: @Ravi . . . This is a window function.  I think you need to learn SQL better.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT  ID ,
            Value ,
            (select sum(case when Type = 'IN' then Value 
                             when Type='OUT' then (0-value) end) 
             FROM dbo.Reestr y where x.Id>=y.id) AS RunningTotal
    FROM    dbo.Reestr x
    ORDER BY 1 ,2 ,3;
```